# How can I send an audio re-recordered by whatsapp without distortion

Tags: sound-design, audio-restoration, production-audio, production-sound

The problem is that I want to send many customers the same explanation about something and I have to do it out loud through a voice note on WhatsApp, I can't send a file recorded with the audio explanation because WhatsApp shows it in the conversation as a sound file instead of a voice note, I have to do it always speaking in a voice note, but there are some parts that are exactly the same and I want to automate them, so I found a way to play an audio file on my phone While recording the voice memo for the client, this solves the problem about how whatsapp shows the message (such as a voice memo instead of an audio file) but the new voice memo re-recorded sounds with some distortion.

So I have an original audio file A, and when I record it by playing it on the same phone, the result in the new voice note is a bit distorted, let's call it B. Can I edit the original A file in a new C file to anticipate that distortion?

My idea is that at the time of recording the voice note while playing the audio C on the same cell phone, the result for those who receive it sounds as close as possible to A, is this possible?

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: you're playing back an audio file on the phone, via its speaker, into your microphone? That's not going to give good results.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing, I understand what you said but,I want to know if is possible to anticipate that distortion for better results

Comment: Quick answer - no, it isn't possible to anticipate that distortion. By playing it through low-quality audio components you are removing vital information which you can't recover.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to create an audio file that, when played through a speaker that distorts, somehow compensates for that distortion.

That's generally impossible, because the distortion is an unpredictable, chaotic 'signal' that's added to your audio. It depends on the exact volume of the audio, the loudspeaker, other sounds in the room, and (because you're using a phone) things like the position of the hand that's holding the phone, the phone cover you're using etc.

You need to find a different workflow. The first step would be to get rid of WhatsApp, and move to a chat application that can run on a PC. This will allow you to use an audio routing application that will play back audio directly into the chat, rather than having to play it via a loudspeaker and microphone.